# set of all $2\times 2$ matrcies having neither eigen value is real

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, lie-groups

Could any one tell me whether the following subsets of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ are open, closed or neither open nor closed?

1. set of all  $2\times 2$ matrcies having neither eigen value is real.
2. set of all  $2\times 2$ matrcies having oth eigen value is real.

Thanks for helping I have no idea how to proceed  just from the knowledge of eigen values  to know such  subsets are closed or open or etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the characteristic polynomial $f$ of a generic matrix $A$. The coefficients of $f$ are polynomials in the entries of $A$. Now how do you express your conditions defining the two sets in terms of the coefficients of $f$?

Comment: I must say i have not understood a bit

Comment: Ok, do you know what the characteristic polynomial is?

Comment: If $A = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{22}\end{bmatrix}$, write $f$ in terms of the $a_{ij}$. Now what's the relation between $f$ and the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: So the eigenvalues are the roots of $f$. Now consider the discriminant conditions for $f$ to have two non-real roots, or two real roots. You will end up with your two sets being the counterimages of an open (resp. closed) set under a continuous function.

Comment: Actually $\ge 0$ (two coincident real roots). So you see, $g(A) = (a_{11} + a_{22})^{2} - 4 (a_{11}a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21})$ is a continuous function $g : M_{2}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$, and your set is the preimage of the closed set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ge 0 \}$.

Comment: I think you should consider a map like $g$ from matrices to the reals. And then whether $> 0$ or $\ge 0$ is a matter of definitions.

Comment: You're welcome. I am not sure about a proper reference, but the first one that comes to my mind is Lang's superb Linear Algebra.

Comment: Will be glad to try if I can find the time.